# perl regular expression to match between a fixed keyword and another two variable keywords

Tags: regex, perl

I need to write a regex in perl to do the following.

The starting line is keyword1 (like "this is keyword1"), and the ending line is either keyword2 (like "end1 here") or keyword3 (like "end2 here"). For example, the text file may look like:

```
*********** this is keyword1***********
*****
..
*******apple***********
******
..
*********** this is keyword1***********
*****
..
*******orange***********
******
..
*********** this is keyword1***********
*****
..
*******orange***********
******
..
```

My task is to match those blocks

```
*********** this is keyword1***********
*****
..(comment: no "this is keyword1" here)
*******apple***********
```

or

```
*********** this is keyword1***********
*****
.. (comment: no "this is keyword1" here)
*******orange***********
```

Appreciate your help!

Comment: You have to give us real examples. Are the asterisks always present? Is the word "end" always present?  Do end keywords share any common features?  Your problem statement is too abstract to be answered.

Comment: My problem statement is quite accurate. Just think * represents any character, and .. represents multiple lines without the three key "phrases" "this is keyword1", "end1 here", and "end2 here"

Comment: the three key "phrases" are the exact things I want to match on. Does this make sense?

Comment: 1. Given a list of 'phrases'.  2.  Match all lines containing any of these phrases, and all lines between two successive matches.  Yes?

Comment: Hi Jim, it is one 'phrase' is common to denote the starting line, and a bunch of ending 'phrases'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My previous answer missed your revised requirements. Here is the updated code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use 5.012;
use strict;
use warnings;

my $text = do { local $/; <DATA> };
my $pat = qr{
    (
        [^\n]*?
        keyword1
        .*?
        (?:apple|orange)
        [^\n]*?
        \n
    )
}sx;

my $result;

while ($text =~ /$pat/g) {
    $result .= "[[[\n$1]]]\n";
}

say $result;


__DATA__
*********** this is keyword1***********
*****
..(comment: no "this is keyword1" here)
*******apple***********
*****
..
*********** this is keyword1***********
*****
..
*******apple***********
******
..
*********** this is keyword1***********
*****
.. (comment: no "this is keyword1" here)
*******orange***********
*****
..
*********** this is keyword1***********
*****
..
*******orange***********
******
..
*********** this is keyword1***********
*****
..
*******orange***********
******
..
```

Output:

```
[[[
*********** this is keyword1***********
*****
..(comment: no "this is keyword1" here)
*******apple***********
]]]
[[[
*********** this is keyword1***********
*****
..
*******apple***********
]]]
[[[
*********** this is keyword1***********
*****
.. (comment: no "this is keyword1" here)
*******orange***********
]]]
[[[
*********** this is keyword1***********
*****
..
*******orange***********
]]]
[[[
*********** this is keyword1***********
*****
..
*******orange***********
]]]
```

The brackets are there to visually verify that correct blocks were matched.

Answer (score 1):

#### Original Suggested Solution

Note that originally 'apple' was spelled 'end1 here' and 'orange' was originally spelled 'end2 here'.

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my $printing = 0;

while (<>)
{
    $printing = 1 if m/this is keyword1/;
    print if $printing;
    $printing = 0 if m/end[12] here/;
}
```

If you want to exclude the end lines from the output, then move that test above the print.  If you want to exclude the opening lines from the output, then move that test below the print.  Clearly, if you can't combine the two end patterns as easily as in the example, you can simply have two lines:

```
    $printing = 0 if m/the first end pattern/;
    $printing = 0 if m/a radically different end marker/;
```

For the sample data, the output is:

```
*********** this is keyword1***********
*****
..
*******end1 here***********
*********** this is keyword1***********
*****
..
*******end1 here***********
*********** this is keyword1***********
*****
..
*******end2 here***********
```

---

#### Revised requirements — Revised program

One simple way to meet the revised output requirement is simply to accumulate lines into a string when `$printing = 1`:

```
my $saving = 0;
my $result;

while (<>)
{
    $saving  = 1  if m/this is keyword1/;
    $result .= $_ if $saving;
    $saving  = 0  if m/end[12] here/;
}
```

However, this doesn't slurp the whole file into memory, nor does it use `m//g`, so it doesn't meet the mechanisms defined for the revised requirements.

With the revised requirements, I think this code does more or less what you want:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my $file;
{
    local $/;
    $file = <>;
}

my $result;
while ($file =~ m/(^[^\n]*this is keyword1.*?end[12] here[^\n]*$)/gms)
{
    print "Found: $1\n";
    $result .= "$1\n";
}

print "Overall set of matched material:\n";
print $result;
```

Clearly, you can omit the printing in the loop if you don't want each paragraph as it is found.  Note the use of the non-greedy `.*?` to stop the scan in the middle, and the uses of `^` and `$` along with the `/m` (multi-line) modifier to pick up the whole lines.

The output on the sample data is:

```
Found: *********** this is keyword1***********
*****
..
*******end1 here***********
Found: *********** this is keyword1***********
*****
..
*******end1 here***********
Found: *********** this is keyword1***********
*****
..
*******end2 here***********
Overall set of matched material:
*********** this is keyword1***********
*****
..
*******end1 here***********
*********** this is keyword1***********
*****
..
*******end1 here***********
*********** this is keyword1***********
*****
..
*******end2 here***********
```

---

#### Re-revised Requirements — Re-revised Solution

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my $file;
{
    local $/;
    $file = <>;
}

my $result;
while ($file =~ m/(^[^\n]*this is keyword1.*?(apple|orange)[^\n]*$)/gms)
{
    print "Found: $1\n";
    $result .= "$1\n";
}

print "Overall set of matched material:\n";
print $result;
```

Sample data

```
*********** this is keyword1***********
*****
..
*******orange***********
******
..
*********** this is keyword1***********
*****
..
*******orange***********
******
..
*********** this is keyword1***********
*****
..
*******apple***********
******
```

Sample output

```
Found: *********** this is keyword1***********
*****
..
*******orange***********
Found: *********** this is keyword1***********
*****
..
*******orange***********
Found: *********** this is keyword1***********
*****
..
*******apple***********
Overall set of matched material:
*********** this is keyword1***********
*****
..
*******orange***********
*********** this is keyword1***********
*****
..
*******orange***********
*********** this is keyword1***********
*****
..
*******apple***********
$
```

Comment: Is there any better way, if I read the whole file into memory already rather than reading line by line? Thank you.

Comment: You can do it that way if you want...be precise in your question.  How do you want the file read into memory?  One single humongous string, or one element of an array per line, or something else?  What do you want done with the non-matching lines?

Comment: I used undef $/ to read in the whole file as a single humongous string and ideally I want to learn how to do matching with m//g pattern with this problem if that is possible and easy. Hope you can teach me some tricks. I even tried things like negative lookahead.

Comment: If you're going to modify `$/`, use `local`:  `my $file; { local $/; $file = <$input>; }`.  Don't `undef $/;` and do minimize the scope of the localized setting.  Once you've got the the file in memory, what do you want next?  Capture the matchable material into a new array element per block?

Comment: I just want a scalar string containing the lines matched.

Comment: if i had orange and apple, how can i make your second approach work? many thanks!

Comment: Que?  Do you mean that '`end1 here`' should be spelled '`apple`' and '`end2 here`' should be spelled '`orange`'?  If so, you have to do some of the thinking; it is trivial to use alternation in a regular expression, is it not?  If you mean something else, you need to explain.  Also, people don't like being led down the garden path with never-ending question extensions.  Ask the question you want to ask first time; specify what you want completely.  Let people provide the answer to that.  Don't make them play 'Twenty Questions'.

Comment: that is exactly why this problem gets tricky! Using alternation, depending on whether you put "apple" or "orange" first, both will match, but the .*? will potentially include "this is keyword1", which I said in my original post to avoid. That is why the problem isn't as simple as this solution suggests.

Comment: If you want to wring the utmost complexity out of your regexes, read Jeff Friedl's [Mastering Regular Expressions](http://regex.info).  If you want to get the job done, do it in the easiest way possible, not the most difficult.

Comment: are you giving up? lol, just kidding. so you are saying "Original Suggested Solution" is the easiest way possible?

Comment: I'm not going to edit my answer again. If you have new requirements, go put the lessons learned here into practice. The code works for the simple apples and oranges cases you show. I can devise inputs where keyword1 would appear where you don't want it to appear. If I was faced with that as requirement, I would not approach the problem using slurp; I'd use the 'read line by line and include the bits I need' mechanism, saving the matching lines into an intermediate variable so that if keyword1 appeared while I was collecting data, I could throw the previous material away and start over.